# When to optimize a Solr Index

Tags: solr, plone

I am using the Collective Solr 4.1.0 Search on our Plone 4.2.6 system. We have not deployed the Solr search to our live system yet, so I'm free to test and develop. I recently gathered some knowledge about the Optimize option for the Solr Index.
During my investivations, I found quite a few warnings not to optimize in the course of development since that could easily cause bad readability.

My question now is: Does that only concern raw index data, which probably would not affect my work with that index, or would it yield more problems to address during the development process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question and concern is little unclear, can you please clarify it.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Basically what I'm asking is whether the Optimizing option can complicate development in any way - like reorganizing index in a way I can't address fields the same way as before - or whether that is nothing to worry about.

Comment: The indexes will be accessible same way whether, optimized or not. The above duplicate link provides good summary of it.

Comment: Alright. This was just me extra checking for any harm this could do to my system, but I consider this clarified now. Thanks!